# Remote MSI Install Progress via WMI

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, wmi

I am installing an MSI on a remote machine via the WMI method `Win32_Product.Install`. After invoking `Install` is it possible to get the installation progress via WMI? I'd like to report the status back up to another application, ultimately displaying a progress bar.

I know `MsiInterop` can provide installation progress, but I don't think it can work remotely.

Comment: hey it's not really an appropriate comment but i have to ask u because i'm stuck , i'm trying to use that methode to install an msi (wmi) but i got each time an error 1601 that means that it couldn't access to windows installer services how did you do it ?

Comment: Are your WMI credentials an admin on the remote machine?

Comment: yes , i'm using c# to use wmi , in the connection options i did do `connection.EnablePrivileges = true;` and i disabled both fire wall in both computers

Comment: [here is my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180599/windows-management-instrumentation-msi-install-remote-machine)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that method has any ability to hook the install messages. I think you'd have to write your own EXE to get the status messages and then marshal them back to your calling program.

Comment: I just discovered MsiInterop which appears to have this ability. I don't know if MsiInterop can remotely install anything though. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/msiinterop.aspx?msg=1042756

Comment: Take a look at Windows Installer XML.  It has a feature called Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF)  that includes a much better interop namespace (Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller)  The Installer class can set an external UI and that can get your messages.

Comment: I found that in the WiX SDK folder, but browsing around the docs, I don't see any way to kick off a remote install. I may just have to use the remote agent approach you suggested.

Comment: Yes, this would be part of that remote agent. I've written some crazy powershell scripts along these lines.  You could inline the MsiInterop.cs code into an Add-Type send it over WinRM and execute it.   That said we only use that for edge case stuff.  Usually I advertise my MSIs using SCCM 2012.

Comment: The use case here is to have minimal dependencies, since customers won't necessarily have System Center or even want it. So, I am writing up a little self-hosted net.tcp WCF service that will act as the remote agent. This will use MSI Interop to hopefully do what I need. Thanks!!!

Comment: FYI you can also use ILMerge to pack a DLL.  But for light weight stuff MsiInterop.cs can work.

Comment: I'm not sure how ILMerge has anything to do with MSI...?